# How do I create multiple route files in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

What's the best approach in Rails 4 to define routes from multiple files?  Should I be creating them and using some kind of include mechanism from `routes.rb`, or is there something else I should be doing?

I'm aware of a new feature in Rails 4 called `concerns`, although they seem unrelated to what I'm trying to do.  I don't want to modify existing routes, I just want to split my definitions up into multiple files to prevent `routes.rb` from getting too big.

Answer (score 5):

In your application.rb file:

```
routes = Dir[Rails.root.join("config/routes/*.rb")] + config.paths['config/routes.rb']
config.paths['config/routes.rb'] = routes
```

You can define routes in any file under "config/routes" as in:

```
# config/routes/api_routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do 
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

In Rails 4 it looks like the key on config.paths changed from 'config/routes' to 'config/routes.rb'

Answer (score 0):

You should keep them all in one file and namespace anything you need to separate.

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :your_model
  end
end
```

Then you put the api controllers in the directory controllers/api/your_model_controller.rb

I've done this for API's before and never had a problem, but you should require some kind of validation for the api namespace

Comment: Would you be able to provide a quick example?  I definitely don't want all my API routes being defined in the same file as my web front-end routes.

Comment: Edited original answer

Comment: Is there a way to put `namespace :api...` into a separate file? This can get quite big after a while depending on the number and nature of endpoints that get defined.

Comment: See this answer. Looks kind of hackey, but might work for what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809811/how-to-split-routes-rb-into-multiple-files. Also, I wouldn't worry too much about the size of your route file.

Comment: I worry about having multiple teams (api/web) working on the same project and committing to one giant routing file. It's nicer if they can only worry about their own definitions and have it all tied together in a master routing file.

Comment: If you follow TDD practices and use Continuous Integration then your worries should be unfounded.  You'd find out pretty quickly when a development team breaks the build.